# Storing application information on iOS device

Tags: ios, cocoa, uikit

**Issue:**
Application should store application specific information (whatever information, e.g. is object purchased in AppStore, or can user use some element) into user iOS device and this information should be synchronized between other user devices.

**Question:** How and where I should store this information?

Please, if you have some free time, I would like to get a wide answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I store info in the device using Sqlite3 and sync with other devices using a common source of information which is a Web server in a EC2 instance on AWS(Amazon web services) with webservices exposed to the devices.

Answer (score 0):

> information should be synchronized between other user devices

If the devices that need to be synced belong to the same person, then this is *exactly* the use case for iCloud. There are a few ways that you can use iCloud, depending on the nature of your data: read about it in [Apple's iCloud documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/iCloud/iCloud.html).

If the devices belong to several different people you'll have to roll your own synchronization strategy and provide any required server infrastructure. The straightforward approach is to maintain a database on a server to keep track of changes. You can use push notifications to notify each device of updates, or have the devices check in periodically.